# How do you add a variable to a print function in python?

Tags: python, printing

Ok, so I typed in my code, but I keep getting syntax errors. So, why is it not working? Please let me know. 
Thanks

```
# Odd or Even?
print('Hello! What is your name?')
PlayerName = input()
print("Hello,"  +PlayerName "! Enter your number and I\'ll tell you if it\'s even or odd!")
PlayerNum = input()
List = list(PlayerNum)
print(PlayerNum)
```

Comment: Im also using python 3

Comment: You forgot a `+`.

Comment: you're missing a `+` between `PlayerName` and  `"! Enter your..."`

Comment: Where did I forget it?

Comment: ``print("Hello, {name}! Enter your number".format(name=PlayerName))``

Comment: Oh ok thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 1):

```
print("Hello,"  +str(PlayerName) + "! Enter your number and I\'ll tell you if it\'s even or odd!")
```

or

```
print("Hello, {}! Enter your number and I\'ll tell you if it\'s even or odd!".format(PlayerName))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use format function

```
print("hello world {someparam}".format(name='foo')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code:**

Remember to add a "+" sign between variables and strings to print a combined sentence.

```
print("Hello! What is your name?")
playerName = input()
print("Hello, " + playerName + "! Enter your number and I'll tell you if it's even or odd!")
playerNum = input()
List = list(playerNum)
print(playerNum)
```

As for determining if it is even or odd, I'm not sure if you did this code already but here is what I would use:

```
if int(playerNum) % 2 == 0:
    print("Even")
else:
    print("Odd")
```